# Monitoring ArcGIS GeoEvent service

Tags: arcgis-server, geoevent-processor

I am working on ArcGIS GeoEvent Server 10.7  on Windows Server 2016.

ArcGIS GeoEvent Service is working fine, sometimes  it stops suddenly and currently its very limited data added on it. For troubleshoot purpose we checked its logs, installation details, Java Process but its seems normal.

My purpose is to track its service status (whether its started or not). Can we write custom batch script as [mentioned here](https://www.brankovucinec.com/check-if-service-is-running-and-start-it-when-it-is-not-running/) ?

Comment: Do you have an existing monitoring tool in place for your IT systems? I think there is a health check test endpoint you can monitor for the overall application. 

Any of your services have complex processing?

Comment: @Simon : Let me check about health check test. We are not using complex services.

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/health-check.htm
https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/geoevent/latest/administer/monitoring-geoevent-server.htm